# Running ASP/C# without using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I recently programmed a website using ASP and C#.  It also has a database containing some information.

The problem is, now I want other people to be able to consult it, not worldwide, just in my local network.

Is there a way to share the folder containing all the documents like if it was an html page and people could view it without using Visual studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Host it inside an instance of IIS. So you'll need to install that on your machine and configure it.

[Here's a link](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7) on how to do it for Windows 7.